# Parsing JSON with cJSON

Tags: c, json

I am trying to parse a JSON file using cJSON. There's no error in the code but I am not getting the correct values from the JSON file.

**test.json**

```
{
    "log_enable": "1",
    "log_level": "1",
    "device": [
        {
            "ip": "10.27.15.176",
            "port": 80,
            "max_users": 8,
            "auth": 0
        },
        {
            "ip": "10.27.15.176",
            "port": 81,
            "max_users": 8,
            "auth": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to get the values from the above JSON file.
and one more problem, it is not entering the cJSON_ArrayForEach to get the values of ip and port:

```
void parse_json(char *json_buff,int len)
{
    cJSON * node = NULL;
    cJSON * data_log_enable = NULL;
    cJSON * data_log_level;
    cJSON * data_device;
    char *string;
    cJSON * device1;
    node = cJSON_Parse(json_buff);
    if (NULL == node)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    data_log_enable = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(node, "log_enable");
    if (data_log_enable && data_log_enable->data)
    {
        log_enable = atoi(p_log_enable->data);
        printf("log_enable - %d\n",log_enable);
    }

    data_log_level = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(node, "log_level");
    if (data_log_level && data_log_level->data)
    {
        log_level = atoi(data_log_level->data);
        printf("log_level - %d\n",log_level);
    }
    
    data_device = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(node, "device");
    /*
    cJSON_ArrayForEach(device1, p_device);
    {
        printf("In Array:");
        cJSON *ip = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(device1, "ip");
        cJSON *port = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(device1, "port");
    } 
    */
    while (data_device && soap_strcmp(data_device->name, "device") == 0)
    {   

        F_DEVICE * fst_device = (F_DEVICE *)malloc(sizeof(F_DEVICE));
        if (fst_device)
        {
         // if true, it will get the 'max_users' and 'auth' and do the rest
        }

        data_device = data_device->next;
    }   


    cJSON_Delete(node);
}
```

I tried printing some values and here is the result:

```
log_enable - 81
log_level - 0
```

Comment: `log_level = atoi(data_log_level->data); printf("log_level - %d\n",log_level->data);` Is that the real code? `log_level` is not defined anywhere. Even worse, it's used as an `int` in the first expression but then dereferenced as a pointer in the second.

Comment: @kaylum, those are extern variables

Comment: But how does being an extern variable make it ok to use it as both an `int` and a pointer? Perhaps you just made a mistake in typing. All the more reason for you to give us real and complete code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @kaylum, I am doing an atoi for that, you can check clearly. It works fine without any error

Comment: `log_level = atoi(data_log_level->data);` that means `log_level` is an `int` as `atoi` returns an `int.` On the next line you dereference the same `log_level` variable, `log_level->data`, which means it is a pointer. So which is it - an int or a pointer?

Comment: @kaylum, sorry, I have edited now

Answer (score 0):

String value is stored in the `valuestring` member of `struct cJSON`, so the right way to get `"log_enable"`'s value is:

```
data_log_enable = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(node, "log_enable");
if (cJSON_IsString(data_log_enable ) && (data_log_enable ->valuestring != NULL))
{
    log_enable = atoi(data_log_enable ->valuestring);
}
```

You can check the README of cJSON for more detail.

Comment: not working, now it is not even entering the if block